# Окончил университет или закончил университет?

Tags: лексика

Как сказать правильно - окончил университет или закончил университет ? В какой мере опасно выбирать неправильный вариант (если таковой имеется) ? Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 1):

В автобиографии или, там, в резюме *гораздо* лучше писать "окончил". Почти обязательно. А в разговорной речи можно и "закончил".